# Options to access database without perfomance impact

Tags: database, performance, database-design

Requirement: Access very large SQL database during business hours to pull data every couple of hours / every 4 hours for latest data. Then store it in local database. Another tool will access that local database for further process.

Question: What is best option to access busiest database without impacting performance. It requires only select statement and may join few tables for selected columns. But we need to connect that busiest database every 2 - 4 hrs to pull latest data.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Comment: You can't access a database without any impact. That's impossible. The question: is the impact so big that other applications would notice or that you can measure it. But this is impossible to answer without knowing which database product you are using, what the table definitions are, what queries you are running and what kind of hardware your database server has.

Comment: Ok, I am asking best option that will cause less impact and its sql-server. Its not possible to share all other details that you asked. I appreciate your time. Thanks.